# JQueryMobile gap between content and panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have developed a Phonegap app with jquery mobile. It's a one page app with a fixed header, a fixed footer and a panel that opens from left. Content DIV is white and the panel loads from its default color.

The problem is when the panel is open, there is a gap (B in screenshot) between the white content DIV and panel DIV which seems like it's a part from the content DIV as the shadow (C in screenshot) normally placed at the edge of the content DIV. A listview at the bottom of the panel is stretched to fit in panel's content DIV (A in screenshot).

How can I fix this? How can I remove this dark gap between the shadow/panel and the white content area?

[image: A-Panel div width, B-Gap between content div and panel, C-Shadow of content div]

Comment: please post your markup. and does it happen on all devices?

Comment: What version of jquery mobile and what version of phonegap?

Comment: Phonegap 3.0, JQM 1.3.2

Answer (score 1):

You would have to change a JQM class

```
.ui-panel-inner { padding: 0 !important }
```

or

make a new class and add to the content area's div

```
.myCustomClass { padding: 0 !important }
```

Comment: didnt work. that gap comes from the content area. not from the panel.

Comment: Then add .myCustomClass to the content area. It is not a good idea to modify/override the JQM css classes anyway (IMO).

Comment: Sorry man, I would have to see the markup. Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Finally i figured it out bro. its .ui-panel{padding-top: 0px}. When removed it, the gap vanished.